# A code to decide whether, or not, a given number of different coins possible to form an exact given amount of dollars

Tags: python, recursion, currency

(Using loops or recursion), I'm trying to write a python function where the user enters an amount of dollars (say:1.25) and number of coins (say:6), then the function decides whether, or not, it is possible to form the exact amount of dollars using the exact given number of coins, assuming that the coins are quarters (0.25), dimes (0.10), nickels (0.05) and pennies (0.010). the function can use any one of the coins multiple times, but the total number of coins used must be equal to the exact number passed to the function.
e.g: if we pass 1.00 dollar and number of 6 coins: should return True because we can use (3 quarters + 2 dimes + 1 nickel)

- 1.25 dollars using 5 coins: True >> (5 quarters)
- 1.25 dollars using 8 coins: True >> (3 quarters + 5 dimes)
- 1.25 dollars using 7 coins: False.
- I have the idea of the solution in my mind but couldn't transform it to a python code: the function has to start iterating through the group of coins we have (starting from the highest coin: 0.25) and multiply it by the number passed. While the result is higher than the given amount of dollars, the number of coins passed should be decremented by 1. When we get to a point where the result of (number * coin) is less than the given amount of dollars, the amount should be (the given amount - (number * coin)) and the number of coins should be (the given number - the number used so far). I have been trying for few days to make a python code out of this. This is what I've done so far.
  `

```
def total(dollars, num):
    dollars = float(dollars)
    sofar = 0
    num = round(num, 2)
    coins = [0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]
    possible = False 
    if not possible:
        for x in range(len(coins)):
            if num * coins[x] == dollars:
                possible = True 
            elif num * coins[x] > dollars:
                num -= 1 
                sofar += 1
            else:
                dollars -= num * coins[x]
                num = sofar 

    return possible
```

`

- When I pass (1.25, 5) to the function >> True
- (1.25, 6) >> False
- (1.25, 7) >> False
- (1.25, 8) >> False (which is a wrong returned value)
  Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) from itertools.

Comment: I have to use loops or recursion as am still a beginner. Sorry I didn't mention this in my post but I will go ahead and make an edit.

Comment: Avoid using floats and use int values (representing the amount in cents instead). Comparing floats can be subject to rounding errors.

Comment: Why is `1.25, 7` false? `[.25, .25, .25, .25, .10, .10, .05]`

Comment: This is a natural candidate for recursion.  Given the dollar amount left, loop from the most quarters that will fit down to 0.  Then, recursively call your function with the total that remains and the number of coins you have left to use.

Comment: Looking at your code, you haven't figured out an algorithm yet really. The `if not possible` is also completely superfluous as `possible` is always `False` at this point. `num` should be an int, so why are you applying `round` to it?

Comment: @treuss using cents gonna be a very smart idea. I rounded the result of (num * coin) trying to avoid errors if the amount of dollars given is a float. Am still a python beginner but, as you said, converting dollars to cents will be the best method.

Comment: @JohnnyMoppy You're absolutely right. I had this question in a python book and I don't know why the book says its impossible to form 1.25 $ from 7 coins. I'll post the exact question in the next comments.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Create a program that determines whether or not it is possible to construct a particular total using a specific number of coins. For example, it is possible to have a total of $1.00 using four coins if they are all quarters. However, there is no way to have a total of $1.00 using 5 coins. Yet it is possible to have $1.00 using 6 coins by using 3 quarters, 2 dimes and a nickel. Similarly, a total of $1.25 can be formed using 5 coins or 8 coins, but a total of $1.25 can not be formed using 4, 6 or 7 coins.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Your program should read both the dollar amount and the number of coins from
the user. It should display a clear message indicating whether or not the entered dollar
amount can be formed using the number of coins indicated. Assume the existence of
quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies when completing this problem. Your solution
must use recursion. It can not contain any loops.

Comment: @treuss I have the algorithm in mind, but as I always have a problem with recursion and nested loops, I could not convert the algorithm into a python code

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes exactly. But I could not convert this idea into a python code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution without recursion, but does use list comprehension. Not sure how large your coin set is expected to grow to and since this calculates the sum for all combinations it won't scale nicely.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

list_of_coins = [0.1, 0.05, 0.25] # dimes, nickles, quarters
number_of_coins = 6 # as your example gives
sum_value = 1.0 # as your example gives

def will_it_sum(list_of_coins, number_of_coins, sum_value):
    list_of_combos = list(combinations_with_replacement(iter(list_of_coins), number_of_coins))
    summed_list = [sum(item) for item in list_of_combos]
    summed_to_desired_value = [i for i in summed_list if i == sum_value]
    if len(summed_to_desired_value) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

number_of_coins = 7
sum_value = 1.25

will_it_sum(list_of_coins, number_of_coins, sum_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below the solution that uses what python has already built-in. This will probably not go well as an exercise solution.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def total(dollars, num):
    cents = int(dollars*100)
    coins = [25, 10, 5, 1]
    return any(sum(comb) == cents for comb in combinations_with_replacement(coins, num))
```

Alternatively, if the combination should be returned:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def total(dollars, num):
    cents = int(dollars*100)
    coins = [25, 10, 5, 1]
    try:
        return next(filter(lambda comb: sum(comb) == cents, combinations_with_replacement(coins, num)))
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem without using `combinations`.  This is the algorithm I described above.  You start out using as many of the largest coin as you can, then you recursively see if you can fill in with the smaller coins.  As soon as you get a match, you win.

Note that I use a helper so I can convert the dollars to integer pennies, to avoid floating point issues.

```
coins = [25, 10, 5, 1]

def totalhelp(cents, num, which=0):
    if which >= len(coins):
        return False
    cts = coins[which]
    # What's the most of this coin we can use?
    maxn = min(cents // cts, num)
    for i in range(maxn,-1,-1):
        amt = i * cts
        if amt == cents:
            return True
        if totalhelp(cents-amt, num-i, which+1):
            return True
    return False

def total(dollars, num):
    cents = int(dollars*100+0.5)
    return totalhelp( cents, num )

print( total(1.25, 4 ) )
print( total(1.25, 5 ) )
print( total(1.25, 6 ) )
print( total(1.25, 7 ) )
print( total(1.25, 8 ) )
```

Output:

```
False
True
True
True
True
```